# Accessing all documents which have a specific value in a specific field

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to access all documents of the same collection that have a specific field value.

```
var docs = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                    .Instance
                                    .Collection("myCollcetion")
                                    .WhereEqualsTo("field", variable)
                                    .GetAsync();
```

I tried to run `foreach` for the `docs` but it doesn't work. How do I access each document in order to get the values of other fileds in them?

Comment: What is the type of `docs`?

Comment: `IQuerySnapshot` from the [Plugin.CloudFirestore](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore).

Comment: try iterating over `docs.docs`

Comment: Yes. It's actually `docs.Documents`. Thanks!

Comment: @Costas If this solves your issue will you provide an answer as other community members will get the answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason)'s suggestion `foreach` should be run for `docs.Documents`.